# How do I stop the screen from fading out and powering off, on lock-screen?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen, timeout

In the office, when I leave my computer, ie. to fetch some coffee, I press Super+L and activate the lock-screen.

This results in the screens fading to black, and subsequently turning off. While this is beneficial if I am gone for longer periods (thus it kicks in via timeout) it is tedious, to have to wait for the screens to power back up, when I am only away for a short period.

So, is it possible to disable the immediate screen power-off, when I do a lock - while still keeping the timeout power-off that comes when the computer is idle?

Comment: You can start typing your password immediately instead of waiting for the screen to come on. Usually, for me, by the time my monitor comes on, I will have unlocked the session.

Comment: Yes correct. I also do that sometimes. Also I have found that if I move the mouse or press a key (ex. shift) immediately after Super+L, then the screen stays on as well. But I wanted to hear if it was possible to block as default.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? On my last Ubuntu 14.04 installation the lock screen behaved exactly like you wanted it to but now on my new installation it does that annoying instant fade-to-black after locking.

Comment: @ojrask sorry no, I never did. I apply the 'Super+L shift' key-combo, to avoid it from turning off.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the flavor of screensaver you use, there are power settings for the screensaver. For me, I can configure screensaver settings via the settings menu. It has an advanced tab with power settings. Here is how it looks for me:[image]

Comment: Well I guess the Ubuntu-equivalent is "All settings > Brightness & Lock > Turn screen off when inactive for: <time>"
This was not, as the question states, what I was looking for. I like this.

Comment: Ah, ok. Xscreensaver/gnome-screensaver has its own power settings.