# Don't turn of Screen when locking

Tags: lock-screen, 22.04

When I log out (`super` + `L`) my Screens turn off, but as I often just like to lock my computer when I'm just doing something else for a moment, It's a bit annoying to always have to wait for them to wake back up. Is there a way to just have them Display the Login Screen?

This is a duplicate of [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499021/how-do-i-stop-the-screen-from-fading-out-and-powering-off-on-lock-screen), but as that was last edited in 2014, I thought that maybe since then things have changed?

Comment: No the answer is still the same ;-)  There are options in the "settings" of your sysyem ("Gnome Tweaks" also has options for this). I have my laptop set to "blank screen, no suspend/hibernation and wifi always active". My laptop is shutdown if I do not use it over an extended time as it boots within 7 seconds.